# ¿ Como acceder a elementos HTML creados dinamicamente en asp.net codebehind con VStudio C#?

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un contenedor HTML creado en una pagina .aspx

A este contenedor le añado elementos HTML dinámicamente desde servidor con un archivo aspx.cs . El problema es que después no puedo tener acceso a estos elementos desde el propio código de servidor ya que no me los reconoce.

Codigo .aspx en HTML

```
<div id="listaChecks"></div>
```

Codigo .aspx.cs en C#

```
foreach (miObjeto item in objetos) 
{
   contenedor += "<div><input type='checkbox' id='chb'"+ item.id + "' runat='server'/><label>'" + item.nombre + "'</label></div>";
}

listaChecks.innerHTML = contenedor;
```

Comment: El codigo que agregas en foeach no es codigo c# es javascript para agregar elementos a la pagina en el servidor usa tags de [razor](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp), ahora si quieres leer elementos de html desde el codigo cs basicamente solo lees una cadena de texto y puedes agregar elementos a esa cadena. Pero en si que quieres que tu pagina haga? y cual interactividad quieres con el servidor?

Comment: No aplica el runat=server cuando crear el html de esa forma. Lo unico que se me ocurre es que al realizar el post al evento uses el Request.Form["key"] para acceder al dato del checkbox, pero para eso define la propiedad name igual que el id

Comment: @MiguelZarate de esta manera los elementos se me agregan dinámicamente a la pagina aspx y se ven en la pagina. Pero cuando hago un post de la pagina estos elementos no me los reconoce el código de servidor. Si los elementos los añado estáticamente si.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini le he añadido la propiedad name pero hago un Request.Form["chb01"] debugando y sigue sin reconocermelo

Comment: estas seguro que se llama "chb01" ? si inspeccionas el  Request.Form deberias poder ver las keys que recibes. o sino con la developer tools del browser analizar en la solapa "network" cuando se invoca al servidor que datos pasa en el request. Recuerda que esto debes estar dentro del <form> para que se realice el submit en el evento

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el Form supongo que será el nombre id del Form ? en mi caso Request.miForm["chb01"] ?

Comment: No el Request.Form[] es un objeto de asp.net que accedes del lado del servidor, no va con ningun nombre del form del html

Comment: Lo acabo de probar como Request.Form y en el lado del cliente entre el div agrego una variable del servidor que contiene todo el HTML en vez de hacer un InnerHtml desde el servidor. <div id="listaChecks"><%=miLista%></div>. Como dices asi, si que me devuelve el objeto pero solo los check que he cambiado porque los otros me aparecen como null

Comment: Desde JavaScript tampoco me funciona bien. Si hago document.getElementById('listaChecks').innerHTML += "<div><input type='checkbox' id='chb01' value='01' runat='server' />&nbsp; <label>hola</label></div>"; No me ejecuta el código bien a no ser que quite la etiqueta runat='server' en ese caso me inserta el código pero no puedo acceder al control desde servidor

Answer (score 1):

es por que en asp.net no maneja el cliente, solo lo maneja con sus componentes, si vas a trabajar del lado del cliente, trabaja puro cliente y si trabajaras con el servidor(c#), tienes que trabajar con el nomas. Esta es la mejor recomendación obviamente puedes omitirla pero quiza te complicaras mucho la vida.

Lo que puedes hacer es usar los componentes de ASP.NET que a fin de cuenta tambien son elementos HTML, solamente que los puedes controlar desde el servidor.

Puedes crear un Panel y con el metodo `Panel.Controls.Add()` añadir cualquir item, como un TextBox, Radio button etc.

```
var rb = new CheckBox();
rb.ID = "ID";
var lbl = new Label();
lbl.ID = "LABEL";
lbl.Text = "LABEL TEXTO";


Panel.Controls.Add(rb);
Panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

a los controles dale una CSS clase con

```
lbl.CssClass = "ClaseCSS";
```

para controlarlos con css.

Comment: No puedo trabajar con componentes ASP.NET porque estoy usando HTML5 y CSS3

Comment: y por que utilizas un codigo Codigo .aspx.cs en C#?????

Comment: Utilizo C# en código aspx desde el lado del servidor para control de la pagina, leer webservices, leer bases de datos, agregar datos dinámicamente...

Comment: @Popularfan ASP.net que estas utilizando (las extensiones .aspx), maneja el cliente en el servidor, osea que estas utilizando HTML5 y CSS3 de igual manera pero lo esta renderizando en el servidor, por lo tanto si quieres manipular los datos que traes de tu servidor directamente, tienes que manejarte con los componentes de aspx

Comment: @Popularfan puedes evitar trabajar asi, mandando los datos por un WebMethod y cacharlos con javascript y trabajar puro cliente, pero igual podrias exponer datos si no eres cuidadoso con esto.

Comment: La opción del WebMethod la veo mas factible, ya que estoy usando además Bootstrap con elementos HTML en el lado de cliente

Comment: @Popularfan si quieres te doy un ejemplo de hacer eso, pero usualmente eso es la mejor manera de trabajar, de hecho ASP.net viejo y es poco eficiente en unas cuestiones por lo mismo, con las arquitecturas actuales tipo webservices, no conviene tener ese tipo de modelo de trabajo xD, pero si lo haces de esta manera perderas el scope totalmente de las variables y trabajaras con puro javascript

Comment: @Popularfan igual no veo problema, ya que tu puedes agregar clases a cada componente en asp.net,  por que al fin son elementos HTML, tu puedes manejar todo el renderizado de las etiquetas, son elementos HTML que puedes manejarlos como clases a fin de cuenta

Comment: La solución seria que agregando controles HTML dentro del DIV funcionara igual que con "runat=server" porque esos controles son vistos también por javascript

Comment: @Popularfan exacto, se lo agregas a un panel como te indique arriba, que seria el principal o por el que manejarias todos tus controles

Comment: Manteniendo el código de mi ejemplo al agregarle los controles me los agrega fuera del Div y sin estilos. Los estilos los tengo declarado en la parte del cliente. Me planteare hacerlo todo el renderizado en la parte del cliente

Comment: si tu le das la clase al control, al renderizarse en el html este lo tomara, en tu ejemplo, tendrias que añadir un panel y a ese panel añadirle los labels y radio buttons,  o podrias intentar con  `var div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");`

Comment: He intentado agregar el código dinámicamente pero esta vez desde JavaScript con document.getElementById('listaChecks').innerHTML += "<div><input type='checkbox' id='chb01' value='01' runat='server' />&nbsp; <label>hola</label></div>"; pero a la que lee la etiqueta runat='server' esa parte de código no se ejecuta en cambio si quito el runat='server' si que me lo inserta pero no puedo acceder a los controles.

Comment: @Popularfan por que javascript se maneja independiente de c#, a ver estas confundido, javascript es independiente de c#, cliente del server. Entonces si tu usas javascript no vas a compartir los datos con el server, con c#. runat="server" solo funciona en c#/.aspx, puedes manejar los datos con c# directamente y los controles que tiene "labels", "textbox", "panel", etc.  o hacerle una peticion al servidor y manejar tus datos en el cliente con WEB API.

Comment: Ok, lo que estaba buscando es si había otras alternativas